# Assign a value equal only to itself

Tags: python, comparison, unique, constants, cpython

I wish to assign to a variable (a "constant"), a value that will allow that variable to only ever return `True` in `is` and `==` comparisons against itself.

I want to avoid assigning an arbitary value such as an `int` or some other type on the off chance that the value I choose clashes with some other.

I'm considering generating an instance of a class that uses the uniqueness of CPython's [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) values in any comparisons the value might support.

From [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

```
If no __cmp__(), __eq__()  or __ne__()  operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity (“address”).
```

Would suggest that:

```
MY_CONSTANT = object()
```

Will only *ever* return true in a comparison with `MY_CONSTANT` on a CPython implementation if `MY_CONSTANT` was somehow garbage collected, and something else allocated in it's place during the comparison (I would assume this is probably never going to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `MY_CONSTANT` stays in scope the object it references can not be garbage collected.
You really should *always* use `is` for comparison, as the behaviour of `==` can be overridden

Comment: well... all the effort was done in jcd's answer, but this is the one i'd want to see

Comment: "as the behaviour of == can be overridden" but `MY_CONSTANT == other_value` is fine, since nothing is overriden in MY_CONSTANT

Comment: @iperov. The problem is that if `other_value` has an `__eq__` method, it will be called for the equality test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is a good way to define unique constants.  There is of course, the minimal risk of whatever object you are comparing it to being defined as equal to everything, but if everyone is playing reasonably nicely, this should work.  Also, the garbage collection issue won't be a problem, because if that should ever happen, your constant has already gone away, and isn't around to compare equal to the new object with the same id.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting point. I never considered that some other object might "violate" equality like that. I can't find a "special method" for the `id()` built-in function, I wonder if `id(MY_CONSTANT) == id(someOtherVariable)` can be "tricked" in this way...

Comment: @Matt, `id(MY_CONSTANT) == id(someOtherVariable)` is equivalent (but slower) to `MY_CONSTANT is someOtherVariable`. I would usually reverse that to `someOtherVariable is MY_CONSTANT` for readability